# Как использовать опции --hash-modules и --module-path при работе с jar-утилитой в Java 9?

Tags: java, jar

Я хотел бы добавить хеш-информацию к моим модулям, которые находятсяв в jar-файлах.
Для этого я воспользовался опциями `--hash-modules` и `--module-path` jar утилиты.

Вот примеры использования мною данных опций:

```
jar --hash-modules com.me.util --module-path "dist\com.me.jar;dist\com.me.util.jar"  --update --file dist/com.me.jar --main-class=com.me.A --verbose --module-version 0.1 -C build/modules/com.me module-info.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/A.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/B.class
jar --hash-modules "com.me.util;com.me.util" --module-path "dist\com.me.jar;dist\com.me.util.jar"  --update --file dist/com.me.jar --main-class=com.me.A --verbose --module-version 0.1 -C build/modules/com.me module-info.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/A.class build/modules/com.me/com/me/B.class
```

Когда эти команды выполняются в строке вывода информации я получаю следующее предупреждающее сообщение:"`no module is recorded in hash in com.me`".

Эти команды создают *.jar файлы (модули) без каких-либо дополнительных ошибок, но не добавляют хеш информацию. Мне хотелось научиться правильно использовать данные опции утилиты `jar`. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это правильно сделать!

---

Структура папок проекта [здесь](https://github.com/java1cprog/Java9-jar/tree/master/NetbeansProjects/my_ch1_9).

Мои эксперименты и рабочие примеры команд утилиты jar [здесь](https://github.com/java1cprog/Java9-jar).

Описание опций утилиты jar (Java 9) [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jar.htm#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867__GUID-44BCC07B-1A03-4FEE-884B-EF057B22299F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После внимательного прочтения [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jar.htm#GUID-51C11B76-D9F6-4BC2-A805-3C847E857867__GUID-44BCC07B-1A03-4FEE-884B-EF057B22299F) я понял, какие параметры должны быть у данной команды для решения поставленной задачи.

Примеры:

```
#Create module:
jar --hash-modules "com.me" --module-path "dist/com.me.jar" --verbose --create --file dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class  build/modules/com.me.util/com/me/util/Util.class
jar --hash-modules "com.me" --module-path "dist/com.me.jar" -v -c -f dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class  build/modules/com.me.util/com/me/util/Util.class

#Update module:
jar --hash-modules "com.me" --module-path "dist/com.me.jar" --verbose --update --file dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class
jar --hash-modules "com.me" --module-path "dist/com.me.jar" -v -u -f dist/com.me.util.jar -C build/modules/com.me.util module-info.class
```

Чтобы посмотреть результат работы опций, используйте следующую команду:

```
jar --file dist/com.me.util.jar --describe-module
```

Результат:

```
com.me.util jar:file:///C:/my_ch1_9/dist/com.me.util.jar/!module-info.class
exports com.me.util
requires java.base mandated
hashes com.me SHA-256 85c0539e4ca9a01b00f4c29a1a8b01cd452d1d97f437166b8bb415046dac65cb
```